# Составить программу для вычисления частичной суммы ряда на С++

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Можете объяснить как научиться решать данную задачу, или скинуть ссылки, пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [скидываю ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B+%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Answer (score 2):

```
double sum(int n)
{
    return 1 - 1./(n+1);
}
```

Все предельно просто (детальнее расписывать, думаю, не нужно...):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как научиться? Немного почитать учебники по математике, а главное - порешать задачи.

Но, вероятно, ждут от вас программу с циклом :) - так что смотрите ссылки, которые вам любезно сбросил MBo.